# Add width of the screen to a class if screen width is less than 960 px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, screen

The code below adds width of screen to class .reverse

```
var w = $(window).width();
 $('.reverse').css('width', w);
```

but I want it to do so only if the screen width is less than 960px:

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $('.reverse').css('width', w);
}
```

The code above is not working, could you take a look? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var width = $(window).width();
  console.log(width);
  if (width < 960){
    $('.reverse').css('width', width);
  };
});
```

This way you're constantly checking the window's width while resizing as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are resizing window to check this effect so you need to add resize eventListener,to the DOM.

```
 $(window).on('resize',function(){
     var w=$(window).width();
    if (w< 960) {
        $('.reverse').css('width', w);
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with CSS and a media query if you don't have to use javascript

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .reverse {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Lukas you're welcome. Doing this with javascript will only either fire once (with your existing code) and won't adapt with the window width as it resizes, or you have to attach a handler to the window's `resize` event, and constantly update the width as the viewport changes. Doing it with CSS is more performant than JS, and assuming you want your element's width to scale with the viewport width, this would be preferred all day long over attaching an event listener to the window `resize` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var w = $(window).width();
if (w < 960) {
    $('.reverse').css('width', w);
}
```

Note, add the event management if needed but no `w` was defined.

IF you add the event management in, be careful as it will fire a lot and  it would be best to NOT force a re-flow every time - look into that separate issue.

A link to a possible debounce for the resize https://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  if ($(window).width() < 960) {
>       $('.reverse').css('width', w);
>    }
> ```
>
> You didn't initialize w